# MySQL Data Reader not entering the loop

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have tried many different things but at this point I am stumped.

```
Public Function GetCust(email As String) As Integer
    Dim cs As String = <connection string>
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)
    Dim custId As Integer
    Dim cust_query As String = "SELECT entity_id FROM customer_entity WHERE email = '@email'"
    Dim com As New MySqlCommand(cust_query, conn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        com.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.String)
        com.Parameters("@email").Value = email
        reader = com.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read()
            custId = reader.GetInt16(0)
        End While
        MsgBox(custId)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Return custId
End Function
```

It should be pulling only one column and one row from a table so i should only have one value out of the query but it isn't entering the loop. Seems like its a syntax error on my part but can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the quotes around the email parameter in the SQL string:

```
Dim cust_query As String = "SELECT entity_id FROM customer_entity WHERE email = @email"
```

This will generate SQL that looks like

```
WHERE email = ''myemail@mydomain.com''
```

when it should be

```
WHERE email = 'myemail@mydomain.com'
```

Comment: great! It's always something that simple that can cause a program to come to a complete hault. Thank you!