# MySql Data Reader not retrieving rows

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, datareader

I've come across some strange behaviour when using a MySql DataReader. The query evaluates correctly in Mysql Explorer (that is to say, it returns the expected records). However, when debugging the application, the error reads as:

*Enumeration yielded no results*

Disclaimer: I am aware of the following questions asked on the site

[MySQL Data Reader not entering the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407609/mysql-data-reader-not-entering-the-loop)

[mysql datareader not finding rows c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323607/mysql-datareader-not-finding-rows-c-sharp)

[mysql datareader not finding rows c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323607/mysql-datareader-not-finding-rows-c-sharp)

But I'm closing the reader, not referring to it multiple times, opening and closing the connection properly, and using Mysql instead of SQL Server, so there you go.

And now, here is my C# code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = this.conectar();    // this method performs Conn.Open();
List<Clase> listaClases = new List<Clase>();


string query = "SELECT c.id_clase, c.descripcion, e.nombre, e.calle, e.numero, e.telefono, e.email, "
            + "e.id_localidad, l.d_localidad, p.d_provincia, c.id_profesor, u.apellido, u.nombre, u.email "
            + "FROM CLASE c "
            + "JOIN USUARIO u ON c.id_profesor = u.id_usuario "
            + "JOIN CLASE_ESTABLECIMIENTO ce ON c.id_clase = ce.id_clase "
            + "JOIN ESTABLECIMIENTO e ON ce.id_establecimiento = e.id_establecimiento "
            + "JOIN LOCALIDAD l ON e.id_localidad = l.id_localidad "
            + "JOIN PROVINCIA p ON l.id_provincia = p.id_provincia "
            + "WHERE e.id_localidad = ?idLocalidad AND c.id_clase = ?idClase ";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("?idLocalidad", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = b.idLocalidad;
cmd.Parameters.Add("?idClase", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = c.idClase;
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


while (dr.Read())
{
    var idClase = dr.GetInt32(0);
    var description = dr.GetString(1);
    var nombreEst = dr.GetString(2);
    var calleEst = dr.GetString(3);
    var altura = dr.GetInt32(4);
    var domExtra = dr.GetString(5);
    var telefono = dr.GetString(6);
    var emailEst = dr.GetString(7);
    var idLoc = dr.GetInt32(8);
    var descLoc = dr.GetString(9);
    var prov = dr.GetString(10);
    var idProf = dr.GetInt32(11);
    var ape = dr.GetString(12);
    var nom = dr.GetString(13);
    var emailProf = dr.GetString(14);

    listaClases.Add(/* construct class,  code does not reach this point */);
}
dr.Close();  //close data reader
conn.Close();  //dispose of connection
```

Suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where does the error occur? Wait.... is `prepare` optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a closer look, seems like your missing a column, you're assigning 0-14 when only 0-13 exist in your select statement.

```
SELECT 
0 c.id_clase,
1 c.descripcion,
2 e.nombre,
3 e.calle,
4 e.numero,
5 e.telefono,
6 e.email,
7 e.id_localidad,
8 l.d_localidad,
9 p.d_provincia,
10 c.id_profesor,
11 u.apellido,
12 u.nombre,
13 u.email
```

Comment: i used the ? prefix on all the other queries and it didn't cause any problems. Will try it, though, and let you know, thanks!

Comment: I get a MySQL Exception if i do that. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I revised my answer

Comment: I counted the parameters and you are correct. Table had been updated and i didn't reflect the changes. Thank you